# Using Piwik alongside Node.js

Tags: matomo

I'd really like to use Piwik but what I've found so far is that it needs to run on a webserver with PHP support. Node.js web apps have their own webserver so how can I integrate the two or in other words, how can I set up Piwik to access the Node.js web app?

Also, if I were to push the web app to production, does it mean that I'll have to use two runtime environments -- one for PHP and one for Node.js -- to support the web app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how can I set up Piwik to access the Node.js web app?

I'm not sure I understand that question. In any case Piwik is a PHP application that needs a PHP webserver (will run with Apache or Nginx for example).

The Node application will be its own webserver. You cannot run Piwik in your Node webserver, or your node app in the PHP webserver.

However nothing prevents you to install on the same server a PHP webserver and your node application/webserver and put them behind (for example) Nginx. Nginx would expose the application for e.g. http://yourapp.com and expose Piwik for e.g. http://piwik.yourapp.com.

> Also, if I were to push the web app to production, does it mean that I'll have to use two runtime environments -- one for PHP and one for Node.js -- to support the web app?

Yes, unless you put your Piwik elsewhere (i.e. a second server, or also see the [hosting](http://piwik.org/hosting/) page or even [Piwik Cloud](https://piwik.pro/cloud)).